# Angular - can I use a single function on multiple objects within a nested ng-repeat that triggers the ng-show of just that object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-show

**SUMMARY**
I have a list of brands and a list of products. I am using an ng-repeat to show the list of brands, and an ng-repeat with a filter to show the list of products within their respective brands. I want each brand and each product to have a button that shows more about that brand/product. **All of these buttons should use the same function on the controller.**

**PROBLEM**
The button that shows more about the brand also shows more about each of that brand's products, UNLESS (this is the weird part to me) I click the button of a product within that brand first, in which case it will work correctly.

**CODE**
Please see the Plunker here, and note that when you click on 'show type' on a brand, it also shows all the types of the products within that brand: http://plnkr.co/edit/gFnq3O3f0YYmBAB6dcwe?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
        <div ng-repeat="brand in brands">
          <h1>
              {{brand.name}}
            </h1>
          <button ng-click="showType(brand)">
            Show Brand Type
          </button>
          <div ng-show="show">
            {{brand.type}}
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="product in products
          | filter:filterProducts(brand.name)">
            <h2>
                  {{product.name}}
                </h2>
            <button ng-click="showType(product)">
              Show Product Type
            </button>
            <div ng-show="show">
              {{product.type}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.brands = [{
    name: 'Kewl',
    type: 'Cereal'
  }, {
    name: 'Joku',
    type: 'Toy'
  }, {
    name: 'Loko',
    type: 'Couch'
  }]

  $scope.products = [{
    name: 'Kewlio',
    type: 'Sugar Cereal',
    brand: 'Kewl'
  }, {
    name: 'Kewliano',
    type: 'Healthy Cereal',
    brand: 'Kewl'
  }, {
    name: 'Jokurino',
    type: 'Rattle',
    brand: 'Joku'
  }, {
    name: 'Lokonoko',
    type: 'Recliner',
    brand: 'Loko'
  }, {
    name: 'Lokoboko',
    type: 'Love Seat',
    brand: 'Loko'
  }]

  $scope.showType = function(item) {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  $scope.filterProducts = function(brand) {
    return function(value) {
      if(brand) {
        return value.brand === brand;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

*IMPORTANT NOTE*: I realize I could add an attribute to the object (brand.show) and pass the object into the function, then change that attribute to true/false, but I don't want to do this because in my actual application, the button will show a form that edits the brand/product and submits the info to Firebase, and I don't want the object to have a 'show' attribute on it. I would rather not have to delete the 'show' attribute every time I want to edit the info in Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` directive create own scope, when you do

```
this.show = !this.show
```

you create/change `show` property in **current** scope, if click *brand* button - for brand scope, that global for product, and when click in *product* button - for scope concrete product.

To avoid this, you should create this property before clicking button, for example with `ng-init`, like

```
ng-init="show=false;"
```

on element with `ng-repeat" directive

Sample

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.brands = [{
    name: 'Kewl',
    type: 'Cereal'
  }, {
    name: 'Joku',
    type: 'Toy'
  }, {
    name: 'Loko',
    type: 'Couch'
  }]

  $scope.products = [{
    name: 'Kewlio',
    type: 'Sugar Cereal',
    brand: 'Kewl'
  }, {
    name: 'Kewliano',
    type: 'Healthy Cereal',
    brand: 'Kewl'
  }, {
    name: 'Jokurino',
    type: 'Rattle',
    brand: 'Joku'
  }, {
    name: 'Lokonoko',
    type: 'Recliner',
    brand: 'Loko'
  }, {
    name: 'Lokoboko',
    type: 'Love Seat',
    brand: 'Loko'
  }]

  $scope.showType = function(item) {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  $scope.filterProducts = function(brand) {
    return function(value) {
      if (brand) {
        return value.brand === brand;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

h1 {
  font-family: impact;
}
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <div ng-repeat="brand in brands" ng-init="show=false">
      <h1>
              {{brand.name}}
            </h1>
      <button ng-click="showType(brand)">
        Show Brand Type
      </button>
      <div ng-show="show">
        {{brand.type}}
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="product in products
          | filter:filterProducts(brand.name)" ng-init="show=false">
        <h2>
           {{product.name}}
        </h2>
        <button ng-click="showType(product)">
          Show Product Type
        </button>
        <div ng-show="show">
          {{product.type}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `show` boolean attribute same for whole tree (is in same scope). Using angular directive with child scope `scope:true` in `ng-repeat` helps to isolate each `show` property. I have forked your plunker code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cMSvyfeCQOnTKG8F4l55?p=preview

Comment: `scope:true` - not an isolated scope, is a _child_ scope, and also `ng-repeat` already create own scope

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this, if you don't mind putting temporary properties in your data is the following changes:

```
<div ng-show="product.show">
   {{product.type}}
</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-show="brand.show">
   {{brand.type}}
</div>
```

and then in your controller

```
$scope.showType = function(item) {
    item.show = !item.show;
  }
```

**Alternatively**, if you don't want to touch the object properties, you can create an $scope.shownTypes array and have your click either push the object into or remove the object from the shown array.  THen you can check for the object's existence in the array and show or not show the type appropriately.  Let me know if you need a sample of that.

Comment: Related to your update, please see the 'Alternatively' section of my answer